# DayNight Theme Android

Tags: android, fragment, themes, android-appcompat

I have a problem with manually switch DayNight Theme.

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO
```

this works great and change theme for whole app, but when I will try switch theme manually them is changed only in Activities but not Activity with Fragment...any solution??

Comment: Were you able to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options

1. put that code in **every** activity's `onCreate()` and before the `setContentView()`
2. if you want to change the current Activity immediately, you need to call `recreate()` in your activity.